# SSD1351 Display showing random bars across the screen

Tags: arduino, display, esp32

I recently bought [this](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Newhaven-Display/NHD-15-128128G?qs=l7cgNqFNU1hB4GeP358fCw%3D%3D) Display and wanted to use it with an ESP-WROOM-32.
After some problems I got it to work using [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/27580) schematic and the Adafruit SSD1351 library. (I connected the 13V of the Display directly to a 13V voltage converter I had laying around because the FAN5331 is not working yet.)
I also had to lower the default SPI frequency from 20MHz to 5MHZ in the library because otherwise it would display some random stuff.
After successfully working with the display I slowly tried increasing the SPI frequency again to get the Display working a little bit faster. But as I did this, the Driver on the Display got really hot and it started to show some random bars across it. So I lowered the frequency again and retried it but with the same problem.
Thinking that I had destroyed the Display, I ordered a new one and tried it. But this one shows the bars even though I never used it with a high frequency. The only difference is, that the second Display is not getting hot at all.

So my question is, do you think that I just got a faulty Display or is there anything special that I should check in my schematic the could cause this issue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE!  From the SSD1351 datasheet, the min cycle time for the SPI bus is 220ns (4.5MHz), so even 5MHz is overclocking it.  I suspect this is not your trouble with the replacement, though; the overheating means extra power was being drawn from somewhere, maybe even your I/O.  Check the power supplies and level converters for damage.

Comment: Hi, thank you for that quick response. The 13V converter is working as it should (I use a LM2596) and the USB to TTL Adapter is also outputting 3.3 volts as it should. Is there anything else I should check? Also, I use no level converters because the ESP uses just 3.3V on its outputs.